# [kdb+/q]: Convert adjacency matrix to adjacency list

Tags: kdb, q-lang, k

Given (rectangular) adjacency matrix `m`, how to construct adjacency list in `q` language?

In [QIdioms wiki](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Qidioms#50) I've found solution in the `k` language which when run through `q` console with `k)` command gives me `'vs` error:

```
m:(1 0 1;1 0 1)
k) (^m)_vs &,/m
'vs
```

Result should be:

```
0 0 1 1
0 2 0 2
```

This is what I was able to replicate in `q`:

```
k) &,/m
0 2 3 5
q) where raze m
0 2 3 5
```

`k`'s`^` a.k.a. `shape` verb is missing in `q` so I just did:

```
k) (^m)
000b
000b
q) 2 3#0b
000b
000b
```

Now, since:

```
q) parse "vs"
k) {x\:y}
```

I tried unsuccessfully both:

```
q) (2 3#0b) _vs where raze m
'
q) (2 3#0b) _\: where raze m
'type
```

Note that [QIdioms wiki](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Qidioms) has [q solution](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Qidioms#71) for inverse problem: from adj.list to adj.matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got errors because original Q idioms are written in k2 - an old version of k which modern kdb+ version don't support. A current version of k is k4 and it's not backwards-compatible with k2.

For instance, `X _vs Y` where X and Y are integer atoms or lists in old k2 behaved like `X vs Y` *will* behave in kdb+ starting from 3.4t 2015.12.13: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vs:

> Since 3.4t 2015.12.13: For integer types, computes the base representation of Y in the radices X.

Another example. Indeed `^` in k2 was a shape operator, but it is not any longer. In k2 `^m` would have returned `2 3` for a matrix `m` from your example whereas current implementation behaves like `q`'s `not null` as far as I understand.

Now, back to your original question, "how to construct adjacency list in `q` language". One way to do it is this:

```
q)lm:{flip raze(til count x),''where each x}
```

or

```
k)lm:{+,/(!#x),''&:'x}
```

**UPDATE**: Here's how it works. If we were to build an adjacency list using any "verbose" language we would do something like this:

```
for i = 0 to <number of rows> - 1            <---- (1)
    for j = 0 to <number of columns> - 1     <---- (2)
        if M[i;j] <> 0                       <---- (3)
            print i, j
```

In an array language like q `(1)` can be "translated" into `til count M` because `count` will return the number of elements at top level, i.e. the number of rows. `(2)` and `(3)` combined can be represented by `where each M`. Indeed, for every row we return positions of non-zero elements. Given an original matrix m we will get:

```
til count m -> 0 1
where each m -> (0 2; 0 2)
```

All we need to do is join row and column indexes. We can't use just `,'` because it will join `0` with the first `0 2` and `1` with the second `0 2` resulting in `(0 0 2; 1 0 2)`. We need to go one level deeper, joining every element from the left with every element of every element of a nested list `(0 2; 0 2)` from the right, hence double apostrophes in `,''`.

I hope it makes sense now.

---

Personally, I would not use `flip` (or `+` in k), I can't read an adjacency matrix in this form:

```
0 0 1 1
0 2 0 2
```

I think this is much more readable:

```
0 0
0 2
1 0
1 2
```

But it's up to you of course.

Comment: Igor many thanks, that's helpful! For pedagogical reasons, would you mind to break down and comment a bit on the steps involved in the one-line q solution? Especially `,''` puzzles me

Comment: For the special case adjacency matrix of 1 row and 1 column (`m: enlist 1`), the `lm` function produces `type` error: `{raze(til count x),''where each x} [enlist 1]`.

Comment: @DanielKrizian: The special case adjacency matrix of 1 row and 1 column is `enlist enlist 1` for which `lm` produces the correct answer `0 0`. `enlist 1` is not a matrix, it is a vector; this is why you are getting `'type` error.