# FIFO & Unrealised pnl in kdb/q

Tags: kdb

I'm using the solution reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73157349/implementation-of-fifo-pnl-in-kdb-q) to compute fifo pnl. I would however also like to keep track of the unrealised pnl at the end of the day i.e mark to market the portfolio at the close price (given the transactions occur over multiple days and we know the close price).

```
t:([]id:1+til 6;date:(3#2024.01.02),3#2024.01.03; side:`b`s`b`s`s`b;qty:6 5 4 3 8 7;px:10 11 10 12 9 8f; closePx:13 13 13 14 14 14 );
```

The idea I have in mind is to run the fifo pnl daily with the caveat that the first "transaction" is the previous day end position to mimic an actual trading book.
to compute fifo realised pnl:

```
t: select from t where date = 2024.01.02;
t:update pos:sums delta from update delta:qty*(1;-1)side=`s from t;
f:{signum[x]*x,{@[(-). z;x;:;abs[y]-sum z 1]}[y;x y]{(x;deltas y&sums x)}[abs where[signum[x]<>signum x y]#x;abs x y]};
t:update fifo:deltas[id!delta;f\[id!delta;id]] from t;
t: update realised_pnl:sum each(id!px)*/:fifo from t;
```

Then we can compute which transactions were matched and at what price the remaining transactions were executed and finally compute the unrealised PnL

```
t: update matched:sum each fifo@'/:id from t;
t: update outstanding: delta+matched from t;

eod: select px: outstanding wavg px, qty: sum outstanding, first closePx by date, side from t where outstanding>0;
eod: update unrealisedPnL: ?[side in `b; qty*(closePx-px);-1*qty*(closePx-px)] from eod;
```

What I'm struggling to do now is how to used this logic for the next day and so on. I'm also open to suggestions on how to keep track of unrealized PnL is some other ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach (which only requires your qty/px/side fields) is to keep track of the cost basis (and thus cost avg) of your remaining/unrealised positions. Something like this:

```
q)t:([]id:1+til 6;date:(3#2024.01.02),3#2024.01.03; side:`b`s`b`s`s`b;qty:6 5 4 3 8 7;px:6 11 10 12 9 8f; closePx:13 13 13 14 14 14 );
q)t:update pos:sums delta from update delta:qty*(1;-1)side=`s from t;
q)cb:{(count[x]+signum[first x]*y*signum z)#reverse[x],y#z};
q)update costAvg:avg each abs costBasis from update costBasis:cb\["f"$();qty;px*(-1;1)side=`b]from t
id date       side qty px closePx delta pos costBasis          costAvg
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  2024.01.02 b    6   6  13      6     6   6 6 6 6 6 6f       6
2  2024.01.02 s    5   11 13      -5    1   ,6f                6
3  2024.01.02 b    4   10 13      4     5   6 10 10 10 10f     9.2
4  2024.01.03 s    3   12 14      -3    2   10 10f             10
5  2024.01.03 s    8   9  14      -8    -6  -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9f 9
6  2024.01.03 b    7   8  14      7     1   ,8f                8
```

I've changed some of the numbers in your example to make it more representative. So then you have the avg (weighted) cost of your remanining positions which you can mark to the closePx to get unrealised pnl

EDIT: If this is too memory hungry for larger quantities then you could use a custom representation of the cost basis to reduce memory footprint as follows:

```
q)fmt:{count each group cb[key[x]where value x;y;z]};
q)update costAvg:{avg abs key[x]where value x}each costBasis from update costBasis:fmt\[{x!x}"f"$();qty;px*(-1;1)side=`b]from t
id date       side qty px closePx delta pos costBasis costAvg
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  2024.01.02 b    6   6  13      6     6   (,6f)!,6  6
2  2024.01.02 s    5   11 13      -5    1   (,6f)!,1  6
3  2024.01.02 b    4   10 13      4     5   6 10f!1 4 9.2
4  2024.01.03 s    3   12 14      -3    2   (,10f)!,2 10
5  2024.01.03 s    8   9  14      -8    -6  (,-9f)!,6 9
6  2024.01.03 b    7   8  14      7     1   (,8f)!,1  8
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A clean way to keep track of the average px at which the remaining position was acquired. Thank you!

Comment: My server crashes when pos is a large number. Likely arising from the fact that costBasis is a list of length pos. Is there a way to refactor the logic to use less memory?

Comment: How big is pos and how large is your memory limit? You could possibly run one date at a time and carry state over from one date to the next

Comment: Another idea is can you reduce your positions/qty to round lots? If you have 10,000 qty it will append a list of 10,000 elements, but if you can reduce it to round lots of 100 then it will only create 100 elements etc

Comment: New solution edited above might be more memory efficient